# Creating Neighbors list from objects dictionary

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, monogame, nearest-neighbor, neighbours

Good day everyone, i will asks about one thing for game. Tired to find any example somewhere for this cause.
Here the objects we have:

```
public class Gate
{
  public int MapID; //where gate located.
  public int ToMapID;//destination.
}
public class Map
{
  public int MapID;
  public string Map;
  public List<Gate> gates; //list of our gates!
}

public static class MapsManager
{
   //here the list of our maps.
   public static Dictionary<int, Map> Maps
}
```

Well, the main objective is creating a neighbors list for those maps and operate them. "Map of Maps" for patchfinding. 
Where their "connection" based on gates. Something like that:
[image: MapExample]

And how i can get the List of gates from MapID to MapID in this cause? For example:
We have a map:
[image: LittleMap]

And how we can reach S4 from S5? The function should returns a List with 2 Gate objects, i.e. our way:
[image]

But me completly lack of ideas how to "make them in code"... 
On whole internet - alot of examples for tile-based maps, sadly but no one example for those type of maps.

Best Regards. Thanks for advice!

Comment: Search for graph searching algorithms - Eric Lippert just did a series on graph traversal that you might find helpful: http://ericlippert.com/2014/10/30/graph-traversal-part-one/

Comment: Yeah saw them, but not helps alot for this cause. Here NuGets + linked for 4 sides (NSEW).For example, what if we have a 6-8 gates inside one sector? And they are looks as "pre-defined" routes more than patchfinding.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your comment. What does the number of gates matter at all? It's an arbitrary graph search, you could have 100 gates linked at a time. Your final comment, about 'pre-defined' routes, are you saying you want to have pre-defined "best routes"?

Comment: Hmm, i will check this more deep. But Nuget...How about native example? About routes - "shorter of all possible routes".

Comment: I don't understand, what does Nuget have to do with anything? For shortest possible route, check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: Yeah, but A*(Star) has better perfomance(Optimized Dijkstra). And before - i should create a something where implement those algorithm. Another issue is perfomance. Just imagine 500-600 sectors, and ~200 AI NPC patchfinding queries at some time will cause a lags. Hard question. 99.9% of public examples of A* or Dijkstra are coded for tile-based maps with "walkable & non-walkable" tiles. Not for non-tile based maps. No one example for Non-tiled, node-neighbours based map and not only in patchfinding cause.